# Crystal Report Display Failed after continues usage in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis, crystal-reports

Crystal report is failing to load after continuous usage in IIS. We are properly closing and disposing the Report instance still we are encountering this issue. Once it happens then I use to restart the IIS then it will be working for some time. AppPool size in Web.config is 2000.

Comment: Is the report is pooling data from a database or you are feeding it a datatable manually ?

Comment: The report fetching data from database using stored procedure.

Comment: i think you need to clean the report instance in task manager by using code.